# PowerShell: Expression only with Last item of an Array

Tags: powershell

I've been stuck on this for a little while however I've got an array of People and im trying to get the last person and creating a seperate column with that person only.

I've played around with `@{NAME = 'NAME' Expression = {}}` in `Select-Object` but I don't really know how to tackle it.

Current:

```
| Employee      |
|---------------|
| John Doe      |
| Jane West     |
| Jordan Row    |
| Paul Willson  |
| Andrew Wright |
```

Desired Result:

```
| Employee     | Employee2     |
|--------------|---------------|
| John Doe     |               |
| Jane West    |               |
| Jordan Row   |               |
| Paul Willson | Andrew Wright |
```

TIA!

Comment: That's a strange requirement, but okay :)  When you say 2nd column, you want an object, the last object, to have an Employee property = 'Paul Willson' and another property called Employee2 = 'Andrew Wright', but all the other values should only have only an Employee property?  Or when you say columns are you looking mainly to have this output in csv?

Comment: @Daniel that first part is exactly what I want! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I decided to do here is create 2 groups.  One group contains all of the values except the last 2, and the other group contains these last 2 values

```
# create the sample array
$employees = @(
    'John Doe'
    'Jane West'
    'Jordan Row'
    'Paul Willson'
    'Andrew Wright'
)

$employees | 
# Separate objects into 2 groups: those contained in the last 2 values and those not contained in the last 2 values
Group-Object {$_ -in ($employees | Select-Object -Last 2)} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        switch ($_) {
            {$_.name -eq 'False'} {  # 'False' Name of group where values are not one of the last 2

                # Iterate through all the values and assign them to Employee property.  Leave Employee2 property blank
                $_.group | ForEach-Object {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Employee  = $_
                        Employee2 = ''
                    }
                }
            }
            {$_.name -eq 'True'} {  # 'True' Name of group where values are those of the last 2
                # Create an object that assigns the values to Employee and Employee2
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Employee  = $_.group[0]
                    Employee2 = $_.group[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output

```
Employee     Employee2
--------     ---------
John Doe
Jane West
Jordan Row
Paul Willson Andrew Wright
```

Edit

Here is another way you can do it

```
$employees[0..($employees.Count-3)] | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Employee = $_
        Employee2 = ''
    }

}

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Employee = $employees[-2]
    Employee2 = $employees[-1]
}
```